# How to read in multiple documents with same code?

Tags: python

So I have a couple of documents, of which each has a x and y coordinate (among other stuff). I wrote some code which is able to filter out said x and y coordinates and store them into float variables.

Now Ideally I'd want to find a way to run the same code on all documents I  have (number not fixed, but let's say 3 for now), extract x and y coordinates of each document and calculate an average of these 3 x-values and 3 y-values.

How would I approach this? Never done before.

I successfully created the code to extract the relevant data from 1 file.
Also note: In reality each file has more than just 1 set of x and y coordinates but this does not matter for the problem discussed at hand.

I'm just saying that so that the code does not confuse you.

with open('TestData.txt', 'r' ) as f:

```
full_array = f.readlines()

del full_array[1:31]
del full_array[len(full_array)-4:len(full_array)]


single_line = full_array[1].split(", ")

x_coord = float(single_line[0].replace("1        Location: ",""))
y_coord = float(single_line[1])
size = float(single_line[3].replace("Size: ",""))
#Remove unecessary stuff 
category= single_line[6].replace("   Type:         Class: 1D              Descr: None","")
```

In the end I'd like to not have to write the same code for each file another time, especially since the amount of files may vary. Now I have 3 files which equals to 3 sets of coordinates. But on another day I might have 5 for example.

Comment: look into the glob module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all create a method to read a file via it's file name and do the parsing in your way. Now iterate through the directory,*I guess files are in the same directory*.

**Here is the basic code:**

```
import os
def readFile(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename, 'r') as file:
            data = file.read()
        return data
    except:
        return ""
for filename in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\UserName\\Documents'):
    #print(filename)
    data=readFile( filename)
    print(data)
    #parse here
    #do the calculation here
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `os.walk` to find the files that you want.  Then for each file do you calculation.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk